# Nginx locations: Exempt certain location from maintenance mode

Tags: symfony, nginx

I have a Symfony 3.4  application running on nginx and a maintenance mode is implemented the following way in nginx:

```
 location / {
            # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
            try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;

 }

 location ~ ^/(app)\.php(/|$) {

            if (-f "/var/www/mysite.com/web/maintenance.html") {
                   return 503;
            }
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
 }

error_page 503 @maintenance;

location @maintenance {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
}
```

I would like to exempt a certain location from maintenance mode, so that this location keeps being served by the Symfony application. So that requests to `mysite.com/still/available/route` are not redirected to the maintenance page.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, actually, it was quite obvious. One just needs to put the "if" into the root location block (/) and add another location block with the path that is supposed to remain accessible during maintenance mode. There, of course, must not appear that if-clause:

```
location / {
            # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
            if (-f "/var/www/mysite.com/web/maintenance.html") {
                   return 503;
            }
            try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;

 }

location /still/available/route {

            try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;

 }

location ~ ^/(app)\.php(/|$) {


            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
 }

error_page 503 @maintenance;

location @maintenance {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
}
```